# AltGr isn't working with ibus-m17n in KDE Neon

Tags: ibus, kde-neon

I've added my arabic layout in `/usr/share/m17n` and I've no problem with Alphanumeric and Keypad mapping, it works fine. Here's how it looks like:

```
(input-method ar phonetic)
(map
 (arabic
 ("1" "١")
 ("2" "٢")
    .
    .
    .
 ((KP_0) "٠") 
    .
    .
    .
 ;;((G-1) "١")
 ;;((G-2) "٢")
)

(state(init(arabic)))
```

If I uncomment last two lines of `map` to enable `AltGr` options, instead of arabic I get english! I don't have `AltGr` key BUT I used `Alt-Right` or `Ctrl+Alt` on Windows 10 for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to move `AltGr` part in between Alphanumeric and Keypad to make it work in this way:

```
(input-method ar phonetic)
(map
 (arabic
 ("1" "١")
 ("2" "٢")
    .
    .
    .

 ((G-1) "۩")
 ((G-2) "ﷱ")
    .
    .
    .

 ((KP_0) "٠") 
    .
    .
    .
)

(state(init(arabic)))
```